# Eliminating Duplicate Records in a DB2 Table

Tags: sql, db2, duplicate-data

How do delete duplicate records in a DB2 table?  I want to be left with a single record for each group of dupes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create another table "no_dups" that has exactly the same columns as the table you want to eliminate the duplicates from.  (You may want to add an identity column, just to make it easier to identify individual rows).
2. Insert into "no_dups", select distinct column1, column2...columnN from the original table.  The "select distinct" should only bring back one row for every duplicate in the original table.  If it doesn't you may have to alter the list of columns or have a closer look at your data, it may look like duplicate data but actually is not.
3. When step 2 is done, you will have your original table, and "no_dups" will have all the rows without duplicates.  At this point you can do any number of things - drop and rename tables, or delete all from the original and insert into the original, select * from no_dups.
4. If you're running into problems identifying duplicates, and you've added an identity column to "no_dups," you should be able to delete rows one by one using the identity column value.